# javascript to change font colour based on whether the image is more white or more black

Tags: javascript, fonts, background-image

Basically I have a website with a rotating background image and need to determine if the text on top of it should be white or black for the best contrast and readability.

Can this be done using javascript?

Comment: Bonus question: should it be done with Javascript? If you choose the color serverside you have more flexibility (like manually overriding the color or using a different heuristic if you want to)

Comment: i am open to other solutions if there is a better way!

Comment: @ElleBillias Constantly recomputing it on the server (or even on the client with js) seems like a waste - is there a reason this should be dynamic? Could there just be a flag set with each image identifying optimal color? This could even be done manually for small sets, but at the very least it would only be done once per image.

Comment: I gave one possible solution for this, but @DavidBrainer-Banker is correct that if this is required, you should probably only do it once  (on image upload or some such) and then that meta-data should be saved so that you don't have to do it again and use up resources.

Comment: What is a "rotating background image"? Does it rotate or is it just changing on each request or depending on some theme selection?

Comment: I have a jquery slider "Supersized" which rotates background images, my client will be adding extra images down the track so I thought dynamic would be easier for them to manage.

The text is not included in the same div as the slider and the text is static across all images.  The site is also built on wordpress

Comment: @ElleBillias In order to update your color scheme for everything on the page I would recommend setting a class on the `body` or `html` element dynamically using JavaScript (or with PHP if you do the calculation server-side) and using the class that you set to change the color scheme as appropriate.

Comment: would you have an example of this please?  that sounds more like what I need to do!  It would just be changing the colour of one div with text in it.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did want to do this with JavaScript and you didn't mind that it would only work with browsers supporting canvas, here is a function that should do the trick:

```
function isBlack(cId, iId) {
    var blackThreshold = 127;

    var c = document.getElementById(cId);
    var i = document.getElementById(iId);

    c.width = i.width;
    c.height = i.height;

    var cxt = c.getContext('2d');
    cxt.clearRect(0,0, c.width-1, c.height-1);

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = i.src;
    cxt.drawImage(img,0,0);

    var imgd = cxt.getImageData(0, 0, c.width-1, c.height-1);
    var pix = imgd.data;

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
      total += pix[i]+pix[i+1]+pix[i+2];
    }

    blackThreshold = (pix.length * .75) * blackThreshold;
    return (total < blackThreshold);
}
```

Note that this is quick and dirty and probably needs a lot of cleanup, but I tested it and it does do what you asked. For reference, here is the HTML I used when testing:

```
<canvas id="dummyCanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<div>
    <img id="white" src="Hood_canal_2.jpg" />
    <h1 id="whiteText" style="margin-top: -200px; margin-bottom: 200px;">Text</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <img id="black" src="bw47.jpg" />
    <h1 id="blackText" style="margin-top: -200px; margin-bottom: 200px;">Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: David, thank you for your detailed reply, I added some extra info above about the "Supersized" background slider, and the text being static across all images and not in the same div so I'm not sure your solution would work for me.  I appreciate your contribution anyway :)

Comment: @ElleBillias While my sample uses individual images in one div, you could apply it to multiple divs, larger images, etc. However, I still stand by my original comment that it would be better to calculate this once per image and save the calculation rather than using JavaScript.

Comment: @ElleBillias Here is a live demo of this method: http://brainerbanker.com/canvas_demo/

Answer (score 3):

I don't think javascript would be well suited to this, at least on the client side.

ImageMagick has some tools for identifying the colors of an image and the number of pixels that match that color. If your images are pure black/white (two color) you could simply see which count is more, otherwise you'll have to have some kind of algorithm to figure out where your cutoff is (how dark of a gray you want to consider "black") and count them that way.

The IM method is [getImageHistogram()](http://www.weberdev.com/Manuals/PHP/function.imagick-getimagehistogram.html)

Comment: as the background changes the static text needs to change colour to suit the background images which are colour, but predominantly dark or light

Comment: You could still use a method like I've described if you have meta-data with the image.  If you're loading images via ajax, say, you return an image URL as well as the light/dark meta-data and set the font color based on that.  I still wouldn't try to solve this on the client-side because even if it were possible, just because of the resources it'd take.  The image will remain light or dark, so why process it more than once?